# Need to realign the two rows interior col- of grid in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two rows in contianer.
Now i am trying to interchange one grid element with the other in mobile layout.
But i am not able to get how to interchange for only specfic case as both are in two different rows classes.

For the Desktop app 
[image]

For the Mobile Layout currently it is showing as

[image]

Actually i want the layout to realign only 3rd grid to come above as shown in picture below.
[image]

For the refernce i am attaching jsfiddle of the same. [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/L6ee1nog/)

HTML Code :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="container">
<div id="graphArea" class=" row" >
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
      <span class="label label-warning"><span class="badge">1:</span> First </span>
   </div>
   <div id="rightgrid" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6"> 
      <span class="label label-warning"><span class="badge">2:</span> Second </span>
   </div>
   <div id="extright"  class="col-lg-1 col-md-1">  
      <span class="label label-warning"><span class="badge">4:</span> Fourth </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row borderbottom">
<div    id="inputDiv" class="col-md-6">
   <span class="label label-warning"><span class="badge">3:</span>&nbsp;Thrid</span>
</div>
<div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.borderbottom
{
 border: 2px solid #999;
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Please let me know the  current problem work around or guide me with ways i can do it.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can copy the sections and add visible and hidden classes to them

like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz09xcts/)

`.hidden-xs, .visible-xs-inline-block`

for better usage, you can use nginclude (if you use angularjs) to avoid duplicate html and specify bootstrap grid-float-breakpoint (if you use boostrap sass) for better visible/hidden handling.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Hi,I am using angularjs itself but not using sass as of now. I had tried the same code which you had mentioned earlier but i am trying to see how can use with duplicate. 
I am looking out how nginclude will help in avioding duplicate html  code parts.

Comment: I worked it out. Thanks, I used ng-template for the code blocks and changed it using the conditionally.